# Math problem with coordinates, how would I calculate a certain coordinate?

Tags: math, lua, grand-theft-auto, fivem

I am building a system for FiveM, by using LUA.
For that system I need a specific coordinate.

[Vehicle System ingame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de6kj.jpg)

[The drawing of coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3tZ6.png)

I know coordinates A, B, C, D, E, P.
But now I want to know point G.

How would I do that with math, and how would I do that in LUA ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- P, E, D - vectors
local EP = P - E
local nED = norm(D - E)
local G = P - (EP.x*nED.x+EP.y*nED.y+EP.z*nED.z)*nED
```

Comment: How would it be possible that I can move the target position away from the center point in offset.
So Like I want to go 1 meter to the right. Relative from the target vehicle, how would I do that in Code.
So move P on the Line of DC or on the line of BD

Comment: To move `P` along the line `DC` at distance `d`: `P = P + d*norm(C-D)`